# Simple linear regression with similar time dependency on both sides

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am given two variables $X$, $Y$ of which I expect a linear relationship, so it is reasonable to set up a simple linear model
$$Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon.$$
However, I know that both variables are also time-dependent in an expectedly 'similar' way, with both seasonality and trend. Therefore, I refined the linear model as follows:
$$Y = \alpha + \beta X + \gamma T + \sum_{n=0}^P\left(\delta_n \sin{ \left( \frac{2 \pi n }{P} T \right)} + \epsilon_n \cos{ \left( \frac{2 \pi n }{P} T \right)} \right) + \epsilon.$$

I am not a statistician, so I am lacking intuition here. My question is: is it reasonable to expect, that all the time dependency of $Y$ is captured in this model or does some of it '*stay hidden in $X$*'? Particularly, I would like to extract all the time dependency from $X$ that is 'similar' to the time dependency of $Y$ (similar periods, similar trend). If this is not expected to happen, can you suggest a more appropriate model?

Comment: Can you describe your formula in words?

Comment: Sure, I just noticed that I missed the time variable in the arguments of sine and cosine. Fixed it. So second term is linear depency on X, third term is trend, fourth term is seasonality and last term is error.